# Questions about Openstack Ceilometer meter.yaml and event_definitions.yaml

Tags: openstack

I am using Ceilometer Newton version. I do not want collect any metering sample (I can just turn off the compute polling agent instead) and only want to collect some event samples.

I configure the pipeline.yaml like below:

```
---
sources:
    - name: meter_source
      interval: 36000
      meters: "!*"
      sinks:
          - meter_sink
sinks:
    - name: meter_sink
      transformers:
      publishers:
         - notifier://
```

I configure the event.yaml like below:

```
---
sources:
    - name: event_source
      events:
          - "compute.instance.create.end"
          - "compute.instance.delete.end"
          - "compute.instance.resize.confirm.end"
      sinks:
          - event_sink
sinks:
    - name: event_sink
      transformers:
      publishers:
          - notifier://
```

I thought in this configure ceilometer will collects the events defined in event.yaml only. but the thing is not like what I expected. In fact the ceilometer collect more events than what I defined in event.yaml.

I realized the pipeline.yaml shoud be configured at compute nodes later, then I just turn off the ceilometer agent at compute node to avoid collecting metering sample.

However, ceilometer still collected more events then I defined in event_pipeline.yaml. Afterwards I find that meters.yaml contains events definitions. I deleted them all, then ceilometer only collects events defined in event_pipeline.yaml.

> Then I come up with questions:
>
> 1. why should we let so many files event_pipeline.yaml, meter.yaml and event_definitions.yaml to determine one thing (like collecting which events)?
> 2. why do both meter.yaml and event_definitions.yaml contain event
>      definitions?

Comment: I found this 'drop_unmatched_notifications' configuration the block undefined event notification. and I guess I should not configure `!*` in pipeline.yaml file, which let pipeline to collect all metrics include event type metrics.